# Need help in - Merge 2 dataframes based on a column list but match the rows with NULL values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes which I have to join. I am trying to use merge on columns ID and STATUS. However the problem is if for a row status is NULL in df2 I want it to still match it based on just ID and bring the name.
If STATUS has a value match it else match just the ID and bring the name.

```
mer_col_list = ['ID','STATUS']
df_out = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=mer_col_list, how='left')
```

df1
|ID | STATUS | NAME |
|11 | ACTIVE | John |
|22 | DORMANT| NICK |
|33 | NOT_ACTIVE| HARRY|

df2
|ID | STATUS | BRANCH |
|11 | DORMANT| USA    |
|11 |        | USA    |
|22 |        | UK     |
|33 | NOT_ACTIVE | AUS|

df_out:
|ID| NAME | BRANCH|
|11| JOHN | USA   |
|22| NICK | USA   |
|33|HARRY | AUS   |

Answer (score 1):

You can create another left join by `ID` only if `STATUS` is missing and then combine both DataFrames by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df_out1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','STATUS'], how='left')
df_out2 = df1.merge(df2[df2['STATUS'].isna()].drop('STATUS',axis=1), on=['ID'],how='left')

df_out = df_out1.fillna(df_out2)
print (df_out)
   ID      STATUS   NAME BRANCH
0  11      ACTIVE   John    USA
1  22     DORMANT   NICK     UK
2  33  NOT_ACTIVE  HARRY    AUS
```

You can also remove missing values first and duplicates if exist duplicated `['ID','STATUS']` for `df2` and `ID` if remove missing valeus per `STATUS`:

```
df21 = df2.dropna(subset=['STATUS']).drop_duplicates(['ID','STATUS'])
df_out1 = df1.merge(df21, on=['ID','STATUS'], how='left')

df22 = df2[df2['STATUS'].isna()].drop('STATUS',axis=1).drop_duplicates(['ID'])
df_out2 = df1.merge(df22, on='ID',how='left')

df_out = df_out1.fillna(df_out2)
print (df_out)
```

Dynamic solution - if always `ID` is in list `mer_col_list`:

```
mer_col_list = ['ID','STATUS']

df21 = df2.dropna(subset=mer_col_list).drop_duplicates(mer_col_list)
df_out1 = df1.merge(df21, on=mer_col_list, how='left')

no_id_cols = np.setdiff1d(mer_col_list, ['ID']) 
print (no_id_cols)
['STATUS']

df22=df2[df2[no_id_cols].isna().any(axis=1)].drop(no_id_cols,axis=1).drop_duplicates(['ID'])
df_out2 = df1.merge(df22, on='ID',how='left')

df_out = df_out1.fillna(df_out2)
print (df_out)
   ID      STATUS   NAME BRANCH
0  11      ACTIVE   John    USA
1  22     DORMANT   NICK     UK
2  33  NOT_ACTIVE  HARRY    AUS
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. The only problem is my dataframe is dynamic and may have multiple columns in it. I create the merge list based on the dynamic columns added to the df2.

I want to merge the dataframes based on non null values and ignore the null values for all columns in merge list. in this case it can be the scenario where ID is null too for some rows in df2 then we match on STATUS.

Comment: @DEs - How many values are in lists? Only `2` ?

Comment: df2 is created dynamically and can have any number of columns based on which we need to merge. I just need to ignore the ones having NULLS.

Comment: @DEs - hmmm, so it means any column has nulls? Or possible multiple columns has nulls?

Comment: @DEs - I ask because how pandas know in second merge is necessary use `ID`? `ID` never contains `nulls` ? `ID` is always in list `mer_col_list` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, that's the problem. ID may be in the mer_col_list but it can null values too. Any column in the mer_col_list can have NULL values.

Comment: @DEs - what is maximum number of values in list?

Comment: We would know the exact mer_col_list before merging. so we can calculate the number of values in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248091/discussion-between-des-and-jezrael).